# clojure: Next element of an item that can fallback to first

Tags: clojure

I'd like to create a getnext fn that looks for a element in a coll and when match, return the next element. Also, it should return the first element if the last one is passed as argument.

```
(def coll ["a" "b" "c" "d"])

(defn get-next [coll item] ...)

(get-next coll "a") ;;=> "b"
(get-next coll "b") ;;=> "c"
(get-next coll "c") ;;=> "d"
(get-next coll "d") ;;=> "a" ; back to the beginning
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

1. Append first item at the end of the sequence (lazily),
2. Drop non-items,
3. Return what's left (`nil` if item not found).

Or in code:

```
    (defn get-next [coll item]
      (->> (concat coll [(first coll)])
           (drop-while (partial not= item))
           second))
```

Comment: Can you please explain each step a little bit more? Trying to learn clojure I am.

Comment: Not sure, I gave explanation upfront. Only tricky bit is the [threading macro (->>)](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E), otherwise the code does exactly what bullet points advertise: extends the collection by adding first element at the end, drops elements that don't match the search item, then returns next item after a match. Matched item would be `first`, we want one after that, so `second`. Look up the functions I referenced on ClojureDocs, there are additional comments and examples there.

Comment: Ok, got it, it's `(defn get-next [coll item] (second (drop-while (partial not= item) (concat coll [(first coll)]))))` expanded.

Comment: How is the appending in 1. "lazy"?

Comment: To preserve laziness, maybe a small modification using `cycle`?

`(defn get-next [coll item]
    (->> (cycle coll)
         (take (inc (count coll)))
         (drop-while (partial not= item))
         second))`

Comment: `count` realizes the sequence. Nevermind. Though you can remove the `count` line if you don't mind having an infinite loop if you look for an item not in `coll`.

Comment: Appending in step 1 is based on on `concat` -- which returns a lazy sequence, which means it's not immediately realized, so what you get there is a `coll` concatenated with a vector of single item.

Answer (score 4):

There are certainly purer lisp approaches than this one but, hey, as long as we got .indexOf, we might as well use it. The key to simplicity is that, plus cycle, so we don't have to check for the last item.

```
(defn get-next [coll item]
  (nth (cycle coll) (inc (.indexOf coll item))))
```

Some test runs:

```
   (get-next ["A" "B" "C" "D"] "B")

=> "C"
   (get-next ["A" "B" "C" "D"] "D")

=> "A"
   (get-next ["A" "B" "C" "D"] "E")

=> "A"
```

Whoops! Well, we didn't specify what we wanted to do if the item *wasn't* in the collection. Idiomatically, we would return nil, so we need a new get-next:

```
(defn get-next-2 [coll item]
  (let [i (.indexOf coll item)]
       (if (= -1 i) nil (nth (cycle coll) (inc i)))))
```

And now we catch the not-there case:

```
   (get-next-2 ["A" "B" "C" "D"] "Q")

=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

I would convert `coll` to map and use it for lookups:

```
(def doll (zipmap coll (rest (cycle coll))))

(doll "a") => "b"
(doll "b") => "c"
(doll "d") => "a"
```

Comment: You would loose the coll order though

Comment: Does the coll order matter in this function?

Comment: And you never really lose anything in Clojure since you still have the original. =)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good job for `drop-while`:

```
(defn get-next
  [coll item]
  (let [remainder (drop-while #(not= % item) coll)]
    (when (empty? remainder)
      (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (str "Item not found: " item))))
    (if (< 1 (count remainder))
      (nth remainder 1)
      (first coll))))

(dotest
  (let [coll [1 2 3 4]]
    (is= 2 (get-next coll 1))
    (is= 3 (get-next coll 2))
    (is= 4 (get-next coll 3))
    (is= 1 (get-next coll 4))
    (throws? (get-next coll 5))))
```